# Android gradle project compiling project in a different directory tree

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, gradle

I have a project layout like this:

```
MyProject/
    Project/
        build.gradle
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
thirdparty/
    ActionBarSherlock/
        actionbarsherlock/
            build.gradle
        build.gradle
        settings.gradle
```

The `ActionBarSherlock` directory is a git submodule pointing to the `dev` branch of ActionBarSherlock which contains gradle build files.

In `MyProject/settings.gradle` I added:

```
include '..:thirdparty:ActionBarSherlock:actionbar'
```

and in `MyProject/build.gradle` added:

```
compile '..:thirdparty:ActionBarSherlock:actionbar'
```

to the `dependencies` section. When I build `MyProject/Project` with `gradle assemble` I get the following error:

```
> Project with path '..:thirdparty:ActionBarSherlock:actionbar' could not be found in project ':MyProject'
```

I can build `ActionBarSherlock` separately, using:

```
cd thirdparty/ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock
gradle assemble
cp build/libs/actionbarsherlock-4.3.2-SNAPSHOT.aar ../../../MyProject/Project/libs
```

and then use it in the `dependencies` section of `MyProject/build.gradle` as:

```
compile files('libs/actionbarsherlock-4.3.2-SNAPSHOT.aar')
```

Now, when I build `MyProject/Project` I get the following error:

```
> Duplicate files at the same path inside the APK: AndroidManifest.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This google group has an answer from Android SDK developer Xavier Ducrohet.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/bPY_Un8BsBY

To quote:

> To depend on a gradle project that's outside of your main project's
>   root folder you can try to do the following:
>
> include 'abs'
>
> project(':abs').projectDir = new File('/some/path/relative/or/absolute')
>
> Note that your app should do a dependency using project(':abs'), since
>   the gradle path is :abs no matter what the on-disk path is.

Comment: could you please paste the resulting gradle section? I can't get this to work.

Comment: what is "abs"? it'd help to have a full answer

Comment: In this particular case, 'abs' stands for ActionBarSherlock. More specifically, 'abs' in this code is the gradle module holding the ActionBarSherlock code.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. I wrote up a more detailed set of instructions [in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/nolanlawson/fe5bfab1867d71000c81).